# How to create an if statement if segment is not selected?

Tags: ios, if-statement, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to create a statement that says

```
if (segmentTitle.selectedSegmentIndex == NOT SELECTED) {
    segmentTitle.selectedSegmentIndex == 0;
}
```

What is NOT SELECTED in C code?

Comment: Its a good practise to check `selectedsegmentindex` because only one index is selected at a time. so others are not selected. :)

Comment: I want to check if no index is selected!

Comment: Then the value will be -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the docs for `UISegmentedControl` you will find the answer:

```
if (segmentTitle.selectedSegmentIndex == UISegmentedControlNoSegment) {
    segmentTitle.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
}
```